# Do SpringBoot's tests with MockMVC fit more in surefire (mvn test) or failsafe (mvn verify)?

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, integration-testing, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

I am assessing what is the perks and cons of using each approach.

To begin with, I am not sure whether a mockmvc can be considered a true integration test, since it mocks internal dependencies.

Even if I used an actual instance with true requests for my tests, I'm still mocking my external dependencies, and I am not quite sure the aim of a true integration/verify test is testing the environment as if it was real.

Besides, putting this controller tests in verify makes my pipeline longer and slower, since it will be interrupted after an unnecessary package and the like.

What do you thing is a proper schema for optimizing these tools in a build process?

One of the ideas I have is trying to use it like  2 profiles:
 -Profile test would execute all IT tests with mocked external dependencies on test phase
 - Profile integration would execute all IT tests with real prod config on verify
But tests would be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Out of my personal experience, we've been in the same dilemma. We've ended up using both types of test:
 - unit tests managed by surefire plugin
 - integration tests managed by failsafe plugin.
Both were running during the build (but at different phases of course)

Now, regarding the controller tests:

I believe unit tests should be blazing fast, tens or hundreds of them should run within 1 second or so they also should not have external dependencies and run all-in-memory (no sockets, networking, databases, etc.)
These tests should be run by the programmer any time during the development, maybe 5 times in a minute, just to make sure the small refactoring doesn't break something, for example.

On the other hand, controller tests run the whole spring thing, which is by definition is not that fast. As for external dependencies, depending on the configuration of mock MVC you can even end up running some kind of internal server to serve the requests, so its far (IMO) from being a unit test. 
That's why we've decided to run those with failsafe plugin and be integration tests.

Of course, Spring configurations if used properly can be cached by Spring between the tests, but this fact can only help and make integration tests run faster, but it doesn't mean that this kind of tests is a unit test.